# How to access variable in child classes which are extended from parent class

Tags: scala, oop

I have a variable *user* which is of type VertexProperty. When I type *user* in spark-shell, I get,

```
res67: VertexProperty = User(273,0,A806683,Gustavo,Wilcox,127,NULL,Employee,1,0,0,1)
```

I can access id of user by user.id, but I cannot access offset, userCode and other attributes in this way. Why is it so? How do I access them? I am unable to understand these properties of OOPs. Thanks in advance.

VertexProperty is defined as follows :

```
class VertexProperty(val id:Long) extends Serializable
case class User(val userId:Long, var offset:Int, val userCode:String, val Name:String, val Surname:String, val organizational_unit:String, val UME:String, val person_type:String, val SOD_HIGH:String, val SOD_MEDIUM:String, val SOD_LOW:String, val Under_mitigated:String) extends VertexProperty(userId)
case class Account(val accountId:Long, var offset:Int, val userCode:String, val userId:String, val account_creation_date:String, var disabled:String, var forcechangepwd:String, var pwdlife:String, var numberloginerror:String, var lastchangepwd:String, var lastlogin:String, var lastwronglogin:String, var state:String, var expire:String, var last_cert_time:String, var creation_date:String, var creation_user:String,var challenge_counter:String, var challenge_failed_attempt:String) extends VertexProperty(accountId) //Check if userCode is actually the code in this example.
case class Application(var applicationId:Long, var offset:Int, var Name:String, var Description:String, var Target:String, var Owner:String, var Ownercode:String, var Creation_date:String, var Creation_user:String) extends VertexProperty(applicationId)
case class Entitlement(val entitlementId:Long, var offset:Int, val Name:String, var Code:String, var Description:String, var Type:String, var Application:String, var Administrative:String, var Parent_ID:String, var Owner_code:String, var Scope_type:String, var Business_name:String, var Business_policy:String, var SOD_high:String, var SOD_medium:String, var SOD_low:String) extends VertexProperty(entitlementId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static type of `user` is `VertexProperty`. This means the compiler only knows it has an `id` field at compile time and won't let you access anything else unless you *downcast*  to some other type.

This works, but is considered bad practice:

```
user.asInstanceOf[User].offset
```

It will also throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if is is actually not a `User`.

This is slightly better and won't throw an exception:

```
user match {
  case user: User => user.offset
  case _ => // handle other cases
}
```

But the best way to achieve what you want to do is to refactor your code so that the static type of `user` is really `User`.